# @RestControllerAdvice not scanned

Tags: spring, rest, kotlin, error-handling

i have looked at 5 tutorials; more than 10 stackoverflow or similar answers but i still haven't resolved that (apparently common) problem.

All i want to achieve is to set a custom JSON upon when exception are thrown on my API. But the Controller advice is never even instantiated (watch breakpoint never crossed.)

Here are the relevant files:

Main class:

```java
package com.bancarelvalentin.plaxdmin

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = ["com.bancarelvalentin.*"])
class Main

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Main>(*args)
}
```

Sample controller:

```java
package com.bancarelvalentin.plaxdmin.controller

import com.bancarelvalentin.plaxdmin.playground.CustomException
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
class DummyCtrl : PlController() {

    @GetMapping
    fun throwError(): ResponseEntity<Any> {
        throw CustomException()
    }
}
```

Error handler:

```java
package com.bancarelvalentin.plaxdmin.playground;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;ExceptionHandler
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;RestControllerAdvice
import org.springframework.web.servlet.configjava.annotationlang.EnableWebMvc;Exception

@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
 
    @ExceptionHandler
    public Exceptionfun handleException(Exception ce: Exception): Exception {
        return ce;
    }
 
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/plaxdmin
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Here is what i tried:

- Adding other anotation to the main and/or the ErrorHandler class (@EnableWebMvc, @Component, some others i don't remember)
- Putting the 3 above files in the same package
- turning in and off the white label page
- add a scanBasePackages attributes in my main class annotaation

Comment: do you have controller in kotlin and ControllerAdvice in java?

Comment: Damn thank you !!! I rewrote/copy it ten times from tutorials (as java). I usually try to make it work as java code before converting to kotlin. But this seems to be an issue for spring.